# Transactions in LINQ To SQL

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, transactions, transactionscope

I am using LINQ To SQL and calling stored procedures to insert the new rows.

1. Does the code below demonstrate an appropriate set of steps?
2. I want to insert (other fours) only if all four inserts are passed otherwise rollback all four inserts.

```
public bool InsertNewInquiry(Inquiry inq)
{
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (DataContextDataContext dc = conn.GetContext())
        { 
            foreach (Officer po in inq.Recipients)
            {
                int results1 =  (int)dc.**spOffice_Insert**(po.Id,po.Name).ReturnValue;
            }
            foreach (Lookups tags in inq.Tags)
            {
                int results2 =  (int)dc.**spTags_Insert**(po.Id,po.Name).ReturnValue;
            }

            foreach (Phone phone in inq.Phone)
            {
                int results3 =  (int)dc.**spPhone_Insert**(po.Id,po.Name).ReturnValue;
            }

            int results4 =  (int)dc.spInquiry_Insert(
                            inq.Id
                            ,inq.StatusId
                            ,inq.PriorityId
                            ,inq.Subject).ReturnValue;                  


          if (results1 != 0 && results2 != 0 && results3 != 0 && results4 != 0)
          {
              transaction.Complete();
              return true;
          }
          return false;

           /* old code:
            transaction.Complete();    
            if (results == 0)
                return false;
            else
                return true;  */
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried the above code, but it does not insert the foreach insert (results1...results3)

Any idea how I can make this work as desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a solution where:

- change the scope of your results
- if a `0` result is a condition **for any of your 3 foreach** that you absolutely want to rollback for, don't increment as shown below. Simply check for `0`, and `break` out of the foreach.

```
int res1=0, res2=0, res3=0, res4=0;
foreach (Officer po in inq.Recipients)
{
    res1 += (int)dc.**spOffice_Insert**(po.Id,po.Name).ReturnValue;
}
foreach (Lookups tags in inq.Tags)
{
    res2 += (int)dc.**spTags_Insert**(po.Id,po.Name).ReturnValue;
}
foreach (Phone phone in inq.Phone)
{
    res3 += (int)dc.**spPhone_Insert**(po.Id,po.Name).ReturnValue;
}
res4 += (int)dc.spInquiry_Insert(inq.Id,inq.StatusId,inq.PriorityId,inq.Subject)
                 .ReturnValue;                  

//no results are zero
if (res1 != 0 && res2 != 0 && res3 != 0 && res4 != 0)
{
    transaction.Complete();
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: This looks about right, although I wonder whether they want to roll back if *any* of the `ReturnValue` numbers is 0.

Comment: I think if any results come back 0 you would want to rollback.

Answer (score 0):

`TransactionScope` is the way to go in my opinion.  I had [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669924/how-to-have-a-where-clause-on-an-insert-or-an-update-in-linq-to-sql) regard transactions in Linq To SQL a while ago.  Although it is not the same issue, the responses I received should provide you with some useful information.

Based on what I can tell from your code your not accounting for the four return results before calling `transaction.Complete();`.  The `Complete()` statement will commit you transaction so you want to make sure everything is correct before calling that similar to how you would use `COMMIT` in SQL.

Comment: @Nisar Khan you should update your code with the actual code because with just the part you added, I have no idea how it works since the values of `result1`, `result2`, and `result3` would be out of scope since they are created in the foreach and you would only be comparing against the very last records return result as well.  Other than that, the code looks like it should be committing.  Have you tried running SQL profiler to see if the statements are getting executed?